# Extended packages for appexchange apps

Tags: appexchange

I have a paid appexchange app which caters to all editions of salesforce. I was thinking of introducing new features which uses campaign object. But this would mean that group edition users would no longer be able to use my app.

Is there a way i can have my base functionality as it is currently and have a add on package which will use the current version? I did read something about [extended packag](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=publish_extensions.htm&language=en)e, but i am not sure if i understood the limitations or things i need to consider before going this route.

Also i see that i need to have this extended package on a different org. Would this mean i need to get this dev org also pass security review and pay the review fee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly build an extension package that will work on top of the base package, though there are a few considerations...

1. An extension package would need to be built in a separate dev org, with it's own namespace
2. If your extension package makes any concrete reference to the base package, it becomes dependent on the base package being installed. That might be desirable, but if you ever want the extension to work on top of a different base package in the future, you wouldn't be able to do that
3. If you plan to publish/sell the package on the AppExchange, it would need to go through security review
4. If you want your extension package to reference any code in your base package, the classes/methods you want to access in the base package must be marked as Global in the base package
5. Once a method is marked as global, it can't be removed from the package, it can only be marked as deprecated